# JSON array field changes to "double/int/string/struct" format in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I have a [JSON file from online](https://samples.adsbexchange.com/hires-traces/2023/08/01/00/trace_full_f3b100.json).

```json
{
  "icao": "f3b100",
  "noRegData": true,
  "timestamp": 1690848000,
  "trace": [
    [
      51213.77,
      39.090519,
      -85.870361,
      4500,
      95,
      359.4,
      5,
      0,
      {
        "type": "tisb_icao",
        "track": 359.4,
        "geom_rate": 0,
        "nic": 0,
        "rc": 0,
        "nac_p": 0,
        "nac_v": 0,
        "sil": 0,
        "sil_type": "unknown",
        "alert": 0,
        "spi": 0
      },
      "tisb_icao",
      null,
      0,
      null,
      null,
      "f9adebf3"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I uploaded this JSON file to the S3 and try to use AWS Glue to read it.

However, in AWS Glue, it read/parse as

[image]

Note `trace` field becomes

```json
[
  [
    {
      "double": 51213.77,
      "int": null,
      "string": null,
      "struct": null
    },
    {
      "double": 39.090519,
      "int": null,
      "string": null,
      "struct": null
    },
    {
      "double": -85.870361,
      "int": null,
      "string": null,
      "struct": null
    },
    {
      "double": null,
      "int": 4500,
      "string": null,
      "struct": null
    },
    {
      "double": 95,
      "int": null,
      "string": null,
      "struct": null
    },
    {
      "double": 359.4,
      "int": null,
      "string": null,
      "struct": null
    },
    {
      "double": null,
      "int": 5,
      "string": null,
      "struct": null
    },
    {
      "double": null,
      "int": 0,
      "string": null,
      "struct": null
    },
    {
      "double": null,
      "int": null,
      "string": null,
      "struct": {
        "type": "tisb_icao",
        "alt_geom": null,
        "track": 359.4,
        "geom_rate": 0,
        "nic": 0,
        "rc": 0,
        "nac_p": 0,
        "nac_v": 0,
        "sil": 0,
        "sil_type": "unknown",
        "alert": 0,
        "spi": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "double": null,
      "int": null,
      "string": "tisb_icao",
      "struct": null
    },
    {
      "double": null,
      "int": null,
      "string": null,
      "struct": null
    },
    {
      "double": null,
      "int": 0,
      "string": null,
      "struct": null
    },
    {
      "double": null,
      "int": null,
      "string": null,
      "struct": null
    },
    {
      "double": null,
      "int": null,
      "string": null,
      "struct": null
    },
    {
      "double": null,
      "int": null,
      "string": "f9adebf3",
      "struct": null
    }
  ]
]
```

In another page I saw `trace` has this schema

```
array<array<struct<double:double,int:int,string:string,struct:struct<type:string,track:double,geom_rate:int,nic:int,rc:int,nac_p:int,nac_v:int,sil:int,sil_type:string,alert:int,spi:int>>>>
```

which matches this new version of `trace` field.

The original data format in the `trace` is gone. Is this the expected behavior?

Could someone please guide me on how to correctly read original `trace` array? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I understand the origin of this "double/int/string/struct" format.

Because `trace` is an array of array. In the second-level array, by default, if all values are in same type for example `string`, it will be `array<string>`.

However, in this specific scenario, the second-level array is a mixture of elements including `double`, `int`, `string`, and `struct`.

Consequently, AWS Glue makes an attempt to parse this mixture, leading to the emergence of the "double/int/string/struct" format.

In my view, I have some potential approaches:

1. Handle this new format data within AWS Glue itself. However, I met error some column in one file could be all integer 0, in another file are actual float. So it will become really dirty.
2. [UNNEST_ARRAY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/databrew/latest/dg/recipe-actions.UNNEST_ARRAY.html) `trace` field using AWS Glue DataBrew for pre-processing, and then continue using AWS Glue.
3. Handle raw JSON within AWS Glue but with PySpark script directly using `explode`:

```py
    df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(json_file_path)
    df_exploded = df.select(
        col("icao"),
        col("noRegData"),
        col("timestamp"),
        explode(col("trace")).alias("trace_item")
    )

    df_result = df_exploded.select(
        "icao",
        "noRegData",
        "timestamp",
        col("trace_item").getItem(0).alias("col1"),
        col("trace_item").getItem(1).alias("col2"),
        col("trace_item").getItem(2).alias("col3"),
        col("trace_item").getItem(3).alias("col4"),
        # Continue extracting other elements as needed
    )
```